# List is not getting updated in KnockOut JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I am working with KnockOut JS and google maps api. Created a single page web application through which the user can filter the name of the place and the markers will be updated on the map.
HTML code.

```
<head>
    <title>Google maps</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="options-box">
            <h1>Liverpool Pubs and Bars - Anfield</h1>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <input data-bind='value: userInput' id="filter-area" type="text" placeholder="Enter your favorite Pub">
                <input data-bind='click: searchedPlace' id="filter-button" type='button' value="Filter">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <ul data-bind='foreach: allPlaces'>
                    <div class="pubs" data-bind='text: name, click: $parent.setCurrentPlace'></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry,drawing&key=AIzaSyAJZiVbDVmFXz8_kPBjfugqCj68BPAKE88&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
var ViewModel = function (googleMap, myPlaces, infoWindow, bounds) {

    var self = this;

    this.map = googleMap;
    this.allPlaces = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.markers = [];
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    myPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
        var newObj = new Place(place);
        var title = newObj.name;

        // Getting the geocode for the place.
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': place.address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: self.map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: title,
                    address: newObj.address
                });

                self.markers.push(marker);

                (function (marker, title) {
                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                         populateinfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                     });
                 })(marker, title);

                 bounds.extend(marker.position);
            }
        });
        self.allPlaces.push(newObj);
    });

    // function to set the current place.
    this.clearAllMarkers = function() {
        console.log(self.markers.length);
        console.log('reaching here');
        for( var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {
            //debugger;
            // console.log(self.markers[i]);
            // Making all markers disappear
            self.markers[i].setVisible(false);
            //debugger;
        }
        //debugger;
    }

    this.setCurrentPlace = function(place) {
        //debugger;
        self.clearAllMarkers();
        for( var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {

            if (place.name == self.markers[i].title) {
                self.markers[i].setVisible(true);

                (function (marker, title) {
                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                         populateinfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                     });
                 })(marker, place.name);

                 bounds.extend(self.markers[i].position);
            }
        }
    }

    // filtering places
    self.userInput = ko.observable('');
    this.searchedPlace = function() {

        // clearing all markers.
        self.clearAllMarkers();
        var p = [];
        self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray([]);

        for (var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {

            // check if its a substring.
            if (self.markers[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.userInput().toLowerCase()) !== -1) {

                // Showing markers.
                self.allPlaces.push(new Place({name: self.markers[i].title, address: self.markers[i].address}));
                self.markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

var Place = function(data) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.address = data.address;
}

var createMap = function () {
    var map;

    // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
    // Centering map at Anfield.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 53.4308294, lng: -2.96083},
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoom: 15
    });

    return map;
}

function initMap() {
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    // list of my places.
    var myPlaces = [
    {
        name: 'The Albert',
        address: '185 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RE, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'Arkles',
        address: '77 Anfield Rd, Liverpool L4 0TJ, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Sandon',
        address: '178-182 Oakfield Rd, Liverpool L4 0UH, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Park Pub',
        address: '216-218 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RQ, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Twelfth Man',
        address: '121 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RD, UK'
    }
    ];
    var googleMap = createMap();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(googleMap, myPlaces, infoWindow, bounds))
});
}

function populateinfoWindow(marker, infoWindow) {
    console.log(marker.position.lat());

    // Check to make sure the infoWindow is not already opened on this marker.
    if (infoWindow.marker != marker) {
        infoWindow.marker = marker;
        infoWindow.setContent('<div id="text">' + marker.title + '</div>' + '<div id="text">' + marker.address + '</div>');
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

        // Make sure the marker property is cleared if the infoWindow is closed.
        infoWindow.addListener('closeclick',function(){
            infoWindow.setMarker = null;
        });

        // Get the street View for the place.
        var streetView = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var radius = 50;

        function getStreetView(data, status) {

            // Check if the status of the google service is OK.
            // In case it's ok, then proceed with the panorama view.
            if( status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK ) {

                var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;
                var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
                    nearStreetViewLocation, marker.position);
                infoWindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div><div id="pano"></div');
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: nearStreetViewLocation,
                    pov: {
                        heading: heading,
                        pitch: 30
                    }
                };

                var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                    document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);

            } else {
                infoWindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div>' + '<div>No Street View Found</div>');
            }
        }

        // Calling the above function with the marker data.
        streetView.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.position, radius, getStreetView);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

The markers are getting updated accordingly. However, the list under the  element which is binded to the self.allPlaces is not getting updated. the self.allPlaces() is cleared in the function this.searchedPlace() and then re-created. But the changes are not getting reflected in the web page.

Comment: Try `self.allPlaces.removeAll()` instead of `self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray([]);`

Answer (score 1):

self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray([]);

This call inside this.searchedPlace recreates a new observableArray, so all subscribers to the old one are left out.

You should clear the array by using
self.allPlaces([]) instead, that is assign to it an empty array, and then keep working on the same obsevable